# Connecting to a local database using mysql-cpp-connector

Tags: c++, mysql

***Introduction***

I am new to using mysql in c++ and have been trying to use mysqlcppconnector for connecting to my local database. I have successfully linked the libraries after a lot of effort. (It wasn't straightforward for me)

***Preparation***

I am using the following code to connect with a database running on my local.

```
#include <mysqlx/xdevapi.h>

void make_db_connection() {
 mysqlx::Session sess("localhost", 33060, "mudrex", "mudrex");
 mysqlx::Schema db= sess.getSchema("mudrex");
// or Schema db(sess, "test");
 mysqlx::Collection myColl = db.getCollection("user_api_key_map");
// or Collection myColl(db, "my_collection");
 mysqlx::DocResult myDocs = myColl.find("user_id")
 .limit(1)
 .bind("user_id","L%").execute();
 cout << myDocs.fetchOne()<<endl;
}
```

***Errors***

When I call the above function, I get the following error :

```
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type mysqlx::abi2::r0::Error: CDK Error: Connection refused (generic:61)
Abort trap: 6
```

Any help would be really appreciated. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1):

`mysqlx::Session` is for connection to the MySQL X protocol. The Error: Connection refused is the very first hint of missing listeners of the port 33060. You need to install and enable the MySQL Shell that supports X Protocol and enables you to use X DevAPI. See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-shell/en/mysql-shell-install.html for instructions.